# Launch Local Mail Client from App Hosted on Citrix

Tags: citrix

I have a desktop application (Windows Forms) which my client hosts on a Citrix server. I would like to launch the user's locally configured mail client to send mail from my application. How do I do this?

In addition to this, I will need to attach a file to the email before it is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure how the Citrix client would handle `mailto:` links (or if you can configure that), but if you haven't tried them, I suggest you do.

Example:

```
mailto:someone@example.com?subject=hello&body=see+attachment&attachment=\\host\path-to\file.foo
```

Also note that not all email clients support the attachment parameter in `mailto` URLs.